# MS Access Visual Basic for Application: Subscript out of range

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting Run-tme error '9': Subscript out of range at this location in code:

```
interval(i) = i
```

Piece of code:

```
Public Sub array_fill(a As Integer, b As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim interval() As Integer
Dim arraySize As Integer

arraySize = b - a

ReDim interval(arraySize)

For i = a To b Step 1
    interval(i) = i
Next i

End Sub
```

Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code (for example) using:

```
Public Sub array_fill 8, 10
```

Then:

```
ReDim interval(arraySize)
```

will size your array 0 to 2.  In your loop the first value of `i` is 8: there is no `interval(8)`

Exactly how you'd modify your code would depend on what you want to do with the array you're creating.